# install libmysqlclient-dev 5.6

Tags: 12.04, mysql, ruby, rails

I can't use the mysql ruby gem because I get this error:

> Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for
>   5.6.15 but the client library is 5.5.34. (RuntimeError)

apt-get is installing libmysqlclient-dev-5.5

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmysqlclient-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 41 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,397 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,629 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libmysqlclient-dev amd64 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 [1,397 kB]
Fetched 1,397 kB in 0s (11.8 MB/s)           
Selecting previously unselected package libmysqlclient-dev.
(Reading database ... 63296 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libmysqlclient-dev (from .../libmysqlclient-dev_5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up libmysqlclient-dev (5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
```

How do I install version 5.6 of libmysqlclient-dev?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the official way , you must upgrade to 12.10 or higher.

But the indirect way is  [Percona Server with XtraDB providing libmysqlclient-dev 5.6](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/percona_server_with_xtradb/quantal/main/base/libmysqlclient-dev) version. So if you ADD their PPA then it will give you a way to install libmysqlclient-dev 5.6.

To add it , do this in your terminal

```
gpg --keyserver  hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 1C4CBDCDCD2EFD2A
gpg -a --export CD2EFD2A | apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://repo.percona.com/apt precise main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/percona.list'
```

Then      `sudo apt-get update`

then try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty. Disclaimer: I'm not an expert on this, but this is what I did to get it installed.

I think the library needed is [`libperconaserverclient18.1-dev`](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/percona_server_with_xtradb/trusty/main/base/libperconaserverclient18.1-dev).

Having installed this, the mysql2 gem installation got further, but I got the following error: `ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension`. In the logs I saw:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [mysql2.so] Error 1
```

The fix to this was to install `libssl-dev`. I also found that I had 2 unexpected / unwanted packages installed, `mysql-common` and `libmysqlclient18`. This is because `percona-server-server-5.6` depends on `libdbd-mysql-perl`, which depends on `libmysqlclient18`. This is documented in [percona server bug 1407889](https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-server/5.6/+bug/1407889). This causes some out of date config in `my.cnf`, but it's not a showstopper.